# SendGrid inbound parse for multiple sub domains

Tags: email, subdomain, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using sendgrid for receiving emails.But I would like to know can I have a single inbound parse setting for all subdomains. For example we will give different subdomain email to all users

user 1 :-  username@user1.domain.com

user 2 :- username2@user2.domain.com

user 3 :- username3@user3.domain.com

.... the same will be followed for all users

As per the documentation I have to add a different inbound parse for each and every subdomain which is a bit complex thing to do.

Is there any way that I can overcome this problem ? Like a single inbound parse for all subdomains for example ( **receivingdomain** :- *.domain.com, **url**:- https://url.com )

I would be thankfull if you could give me a little help

Comment: did you found any solution?

Comment: No. It seems there is no solution @cyptus

Comment: Hello, any updates about the topic

Comment: Would also really appreciate if this was possible.